# Android: layout_toRightOf and android:layout_below

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, tablerow

Here I have developed one app. Here I **wish to need the o/p** like below format:

```
Artist:      artist
Duration:    duration
Title:       title.
```

But **I got the o/p** is:

```
Artist:
    artist
Durstion:
    duration
Title: 
    title
```

Here I wish to need the above format.

How can I do this?

Here I have used below code for my layout file. But I can't get the my requirement output. So please help me and give me some ideas.
please help me

this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/orderinformation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payment_method1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/payment_method1"
        android:paddingLeft="75px"
        android:text="artist"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:text="Duration"
         android:layout_below="@id/payment_method1"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="65px"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/total1"
        android:text="duration"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_below="@id/orderinformation" >   
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/firstname1"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/total1"
   android:text="Title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
      android:text="title"
    android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstname1"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: rtfm. toRightOf is RelativeLayout specific. LinearLayout places items one after the other, so, nothing wrong with your output. consider tableLayout

Comment: why not you use a table layout. It best suits this kind of situations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are using LinearLayout with orientation as vertical you will get every new layout below the previous Layout. Better would be use RelativeLayout. As `android:layout_toRightOf` is a property of RelativeLayout it will have no effect in LinearLayout.

The best in your case would be using TableLayout, just you have to put TextView inside TableRow.

Pseudo code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/payment_method1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Artist"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="artist"
            android:textColor="#10bcc9"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Duration"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="duration"
            android:textColor="#10bcc9"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstname1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="#10bcc9"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i have used this layout on my expandablelistview.here i have to run the app and expand means empty space is displayed here.how can i resolve this error.the screenshot is my o/p.but i wish to need the o/p is w/o empty space.please refer screenshot and give me solution.http://screencast.com/t/psGE5WC4yw

Comment: please read my above comment and give me solution.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    <LinearLayout... orientation = vertical>

        <LinearLayout... orientation = horizontal>
            <TextView  title>
            <TextView  value>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout... orientation = horizontal>
            <TextView  title>
            <TextView  value>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

or use `TableLayout`

ps. not a real syntax for layout, just to illustrate the idea

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion or a beginner, the graphical would very much help you in achieving that. You can just drag and drop the TextView where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use RelativeLayout, if you want to adjust your textview according to you means

Answer (score 0):

Try this This may also help to solve your requirement

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/t2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dip" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payment_method1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="65px"
        android:text="artist"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/payment_method1"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:text="Duration"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="65px"
        android:text="duration"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstname1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/total1"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstname1"
        android:paddingLeft="65px"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
```