# Android ListView toRightOf ImageView with different size without resizing image

Tags: android, listview, imageview, height, size

I would like to have an Imageview (size 50dp / 50 dp) and to the right of this image, i would like to have a ListView (Which has a variable size, depending on my database, but that's not the point). The Image should keep its size, while the List should have its own size.

My problem is: My ListView takes the height of my Imageview on the Left. I want my List to be visible, without any scroll.
All of this code is placed in a RelativeLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listAddresses"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/AnotherImageWithListOnItsRight" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/iconAddress"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/orange_message" android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconAddress"
            android:id="@+id/listAddressTrue" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:dividerHeight="4px" >      
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also managed to have my full ListView without scroll, but if I do that, the height of my Image is horrible... So I thought I could make a RelativeLayout, dedicated to my image, so my Image wouldn't be resized, but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me please?

PS: Sorry for my english..

Comment: Not seeing the problem.  I copied your xml, and i got a 50dp by 50dp iv on the left, and a listview that extends to the bottom on the right, which seems to be what you want?

Comment: pls try this. Change height of RelativeLayout  android:layout_height="fill_parent"  to    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: I put wrap_content and it didn't work..

Comment: It works with you? Well... This is akward!

Comment: could u clarify u'r error when you say you get a resized image.  Is your image extending to the bottom of the screen?  Or is it just the 50 by 50 dp resulting in a disfigured image, but not extending the length of the screen?

Comment: With the code I put in my question, I have a 50 dp / 50 dp image, and a listview with the same height (I have to scroll in this little 50dp height to see the rest of the list).

But after trying a lot of things, I managed to get my full List without any scroll. The width of the Image on the lft was okay, but the image had a huge height (same as the list), so the image was horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here:**

```
<ListView 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconAddress"
```

you are trying to use `layout_toRightOf` attribute, but that only works when you are inside a RelativeLayout, but your ListView is inside the **LinearLayout**

So maybe changing the `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` will work for you, because then you can actually use this attribute

Comment: Okay, I replaced with a Relativelayout.
I still have a scroll bar instaed of a full List...

Comment: The default orientation of a LinearLayout is horizontal, which is why I don't see how this fix changes the result.

Comment: My answer explains why the `layout_toRightOf` attribute cannot work: because it is an invalid attribute to be used in LinearLayout, see also answer of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722246/android-layout-torightof-and-androidlayout-below  => so changing LinearLayout to RelativeLayout doesn't sound like a bad idea to me

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listAddresses"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/AnotherImageWithListOnItsRight" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/orange_message" android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/listAddressTrue" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#FFCC00"
            android:dividerHeight="4px" >      
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried what you gave me.
Now, the ListView is empty (I think it's due to the width of 0 dp).
BUT, the list has a greater height and the image has a good size! (But the list is empty...)

Comment: @user3340507 did you add `android:layout_weight="1"` in your listview.